# Greek Symbol To Denote the Posterior Mean

Tags: bayesian, notation

What symbol is commonly accepted to denote the mean of the posterior distribution generally speaking?

Comment: Not sure there is a 'commonly accepted' notation. If the parameter is understood, maybe $\mu|x,$ where $x$ is the symbol used for the data. If the parameter, say $\theta,$ needs to be shown, $E(\theta\,|\,x).$

Comment: I am looking for a greek symbol (column name on a table) which can represent the posterior mean for a set of different parameters which are the rows of a table.

Comment: Causes of the current mess of nonstandard notation in Bayesian statistics are that the widespread use of Bayesian methods has accompanied increased computational capabilities and various authors have invented quirky notations for narrow specific purposes. Notation has not yet stabilized. // Suggest column header $E(\cdot|x)$ with $\cdot$ supplied by row headers. Or column header (stacked) words 'Posterior Means'.

Comment: There is no reason to set a "common" notation besides the probabilistic ones, like $E(\cdot|x)$ or $E(\cdot|D)$ or $\mathbb E(\cdot|x)$ or ..., if only because there need be one notation for each transform of the parameter.